# How do I fill a column in ranges with values from the same column in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe df1:

```
col_1   col_2
A       a1
A       a2
B       
A       a3
C  
A       a4
A       a5
D
A       a6
A       a7
B
```

For non-empty values from `col_2`, values from `col_1` always have the value `A`. However, for empty values from `col_2`, values from `col_1` are always different from `A`, but they can repeat.

And I need output like:

```
col_1   col_2
B       a1
B       a2
C       a3
D       a4
D       a5
B       a6
B       a7
```

How can I do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
mask = df.col_1 != 'A'

# Index col_1 based on the index of the mask's first true value
df.col_1 = df.col_1.iloc[[mask[i:].idxmax() for i in range(len(df))]].values

# Them simply drop the empty rows
df[~df.col_2.isnull()]
```

Output:

```
  col_1 col_2
0     B    a1
1     B    a2
3     C    a3
5     D    a4
6     D    a5
8     B    a6
9     B    a7
```